# dotenv config path property value not work correctly as assumed in node typescript project

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables

I am working on node typescript project, my file structure is below:

```
My_Project/
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── dev.env
├── src/
│   ├── server.ts
│   └── app.ts
├── node_modules/
└── dist/
```

to use environmental variable in **dev.env**, i am using dotenv package. my dotenv config in **server.ts** is below:

```
import { config } from "dotenv";

config({
  path: "../dev.env",
});
```

when i want access env variables using **process.env.*** it says undefined. But when i set **path** property in config() parameter object to **"./dev.env"** it works correctly. Why it happens? Shouldn't path property value to be "../dev.env" ?